# Use edit box input as rows names in table

Tags: matlab

I need to be able to use the string input of an edit box as the row names of a table in MATLAB. For example, the string will be in the form of ABCDEFG or 123456 with no spaces. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply rownames to the `uitable()` as column vector of type char. Type in the input dialog e.g. `'abcdef'`:

```
rnames = inputdlg('Supply rownames with no spaces');
rnames = rnames{1}';
```

Check within uitable:

```
f      = figure('Position',[200 200 400 150]);
dat    = rand(numel(rnames),3); 
cnames = {'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'};
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[20 20 360 100]);
```